# How to get Product id using Super attribute in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am working on ajax module for Shopping cart in Magento. Consider i have a configurable product with 2 simple products configured as its two sizes (Small an Medium). When user selects and adds the item to cart, i cannot see the specific product id (small) in the url.
But instead supper_attribute is posted to my controller.

Is it possible for me to get the actual product id of size "Small" with the super attribute.

Below is my supper attribute array

```
[super_attribute] => Array
        (
            [129] => 128
        )
129 = attribute_id (Size)
128 = attribute value (Small)
```

Please suggest me in this scenario. Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
$childProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getProductByAttributes($request->getData('super_attribute'), $product);
```

Where `$product` is the configurable product object.

For the [Class Reference](http://freegento.com/doc/db/d00/class_mage___catalog___model___product___type___configurable.html#ed3689b7d9def93867bc28a73faf1641)

Comment: Thanks Man really awesome

Comment: that's exactly what I'm looking for, but `$childProduct` returns null on getFinalPrice()! How can I get the final, discounted price?