# Get config simple product from configurable product options

Tags: php, magento

Sorry for my bad English. 
Hi i have **configurable product id** and its `selected options ids` is their anyway from i can get simple product of this configurable product belongs to these options actually i need that simple product id so i can get its weight.

```
["config_product"]=>"754"
["super_attribute"]=>
      array(4) {
        [327]=>"2148"
        [551]=> "11474"
        [554]=> "11515"
        [628]=>"13239"
      }
```

I have this array i want to get simple product id of this configurable product which belongs to these supper attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this question if we send it params and parent product it will return the related associated product.

```
$product = $parent_config_product_object;
$params["super_attribute"]=>
      array(4) {
        [327]=>"2148"
        [551]=> "11474"
        [554]=> "11515"
        [628]=>"13239"
      }
    $childProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getProductByAttributes($params['super_attribute'], $product);
        Mage::log($childProduct->getData());
```

Hope it will help someone else..
I got this solution from here 
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8536179/2328626)